# Object declaration between classes in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment for school and have a few silly things keeping my from making progress. I've searched on SO and throughout other parts of the web and can't find an answer that works for me.

The problem is the Rat-In-A-Maze algorithm design problem using Stacks and Queues. I've designed both my Stack (based on array) and Queue (linked list) classes and am now designing the algorithms in searchStack() and searchQueue().

The questions I have are:

1) How do I declare a Stack or Queue in my ratInMaze class? I'm including the Stack.h and Queue.h files but still getting errors when I try to instantiate them

2) How would I reference the maze that my professor provides in Main.cpp for the operations in my methods? IE in my code I want it to be called map[x][y] and be able to perform operations based on that.

Here is my ratInMaze.cpp: (Not yet finished, but enough to give context)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "RatInMaze.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Stack.h"


using namespace std;



bool RatInMaze::isValidIndex(int x, int y)
{
    // 12 x 14 array
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 13 || y >15)
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool RatInMaze::searchStack(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
{

    int backX;
    int backY;
    int traveled;
    int thePath;

    //Matrix is 12x14, check dimensions
    if (!isValidIndex(fromX,fromY))
    {
        cout<<"Not valid starting point"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    else if (!isValidIndex(toX, toY))
    {
        cout<<"Not a valid ending point";
            return false;
    }

     Stack<int> ratStack(20);    //throws error
    //Create stack? //ATTENTION
    // Load Map?    //ATTENTION

    //Set map variables
    int x = fromX;
    int y = fromY;
    map[x][y]='S'; //Mark starting point
    ratStack->push(y); //First coordinates in
    ratStack->push(x); //the stack are starting points

    //Load map? Attention
    while ( !(x==toX || y==toY))
    {
        //Try to move right
        if(isValidIndex(map[x][y+1]) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
        {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
        }
        //Try to move down
        else if(isValidIndex(map[x+1][y]) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
        {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x+1;
            map[x][y]='D';
            traveled++;
        }
        //Try move left
        else if(isValidIndex(map[x][y-1]) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
        {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Try move up 
        else if(isValidIndex(map[x+1][y]) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
        {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Else you can't make any move, must retrace steps
        else
        {
            //Pop off last coordinates on stack to get the previous square
            backX = ratStack->pop();
            backY= ratStack->pop();

            //If we came from right, go back left, block off this square from revisiting
            if(map[backX][backY]=='R')
            {
                map[backX][backY]=2;
                y=y-1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from above, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='D')
            {
                map[backX][backY]=2;
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from left, go back right if we can, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='L')
            {
                map[backX][backY]=2;
                y=y+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from below, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='U')
            {
                map[backX][backY]=2;
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }

            //return to top of loop and we are now at the spot we came from before running into jam
            //try to move right, down, left, up again as usual
            //if not, we pop off another set of coordinates and repeat until we can move
        }


    } //End while loop

    if (x==toX && y==toY)
    {   
        cout<<"We found the cheese! "<<"It took us "<<ratStack->size()<<"squares and we traveled through" << traveled<<endl;
        return true;
    }   
    else
        return false;

} //End method




/*
SearchQueue
"Sprawling rats"
start at the point, stack->push coordinates into queue stack->push(x) stack->push(y)
checke every direction possible and change the letter RLUD to indicate where you came from 
and stack->push each one of those pairs to the queue
When at the end, trace back based on the RLUD until you get to where you started ('4')
*/

bool searchQueue(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
{
    int currentX;
    int currentY;

    //Matrix is 12x14, check dimensions
    if (fromX < 0 || fromX >13 || fromY < 0 || fromY >15)
    {
        cout<<"Not valid starting point"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    else if (toX < 0 || toX > 13 || toY < 0 || toY > 15 )
    {
        cout<<"Not a valid ending point";
            return false;
    }

    //Valid index, we can proceed
    //Create Queue, starting points assigned
    Queue<int> ratQueue;
    int x = fromX;
    int y = fromY;
    myQueue->push(x);
    myQueue->push(y);

    bool found = false;

    traveled=0;
    while (!found)
    {
        currentX=myQueue->pop();
        currentY=myQueue->pop();

        if (currentX==toX && currentY==toY)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        //Check right move
        if (map[currentX][currentY+1] < 1)
        {
            myQueue->push(x);
            myQueue->push(y+1);
            map[x][y+1]='R';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Check down move
        if (map[currentX+1][currentY] < 1)
        {
            myQueue->push(x+1);
            myQueue->push(y);
            map[x+1][y]='D';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Check left move
        if (map[currentX][currentY-1] < 1)
        {
            myQueue->push(x);
            myQueue->push(y-1);
            map[x][y-1]='L';
            traveled++;

        }

        //Check up move
        if (map[currentX-1][currentY] < 1)
        {
            myQueue->push(x-1);
            myQueue->push(y);
            map[x-1][y] = 'U';
            traveled++;
        }
    } //End while loop  



    //Cheese is now found

    x=currentX;
    y=currentY;
    thePath = 0;

    while( x == fromX || y == fromY)
    {

        //Check if we came from left
        if (map[x][y]=='R')
        {
            map[x][y]=2;
            y=y-1;
            thePath++;
        }
        //Check if we came from above
        else if (map[x][y]=='D')
        {
            map[x][y]=2;
            x=x-1;
            thePath++;
        }
        //Check if we came from right
        else if (map[x][y]=='L')
        {
            map[x][y]=2;
            y=y+1;
            thePath++;
        }
        //Check if we came from below
        else if (map[x][y]=='U')
        {
            map[x][y]=2;
            x=x+1;
            thePath++;
        }

    }

    //Clean up array, leaving only 1s for the walls and 2 to show our path
    for(int i=0; i <13; i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; i<15; j++)
        {
            if (map[i][j]!=1 && map[i][j]!=2)
                map[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Found the cheese! We traveled "<<traveled<<" squares and the path took "<<thePath<<" squares"<<endl;
    return true;





} //End searchQueue method
```

Here is my Stack.cpp:

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int initialCapacity)
{
    stackSize = initialCapacity;
    emptyStack=-1;
    stackTop=emptyStack;
    stack = new int[initialCapacity];

}

template<class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() { delete [] stack;}  

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const int& theElement) 
{
    stackTop++;
    stack[stackTop]=theElement;
}

template<class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() const 
{
    return stackTop==emptyStack;
}
template<class T>
int Stack<T>::size() const 
{
    return stackTop+1;
}
template<class T>
int Stack<T>::top()
{
    return stack[stackTop];
}
template<class T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
    stack[stackTop]=NULL;
    stackTop--;
}
```

Here is my Queue.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Queue.h"
#include <cstddef>


using namespace std;

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue() 
{
    first,last=NULL;
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue() 
{

}

template <class T>
bool Queue<T>::empty()
{
    return (first==NULL && last==NULL);
}

template <class T>
int Queue<T>::size()
{
    int count=0;
    tempNode = first;
    while (tempNode->next !=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }

    return count;
}

template <class T>
int& Queue<T>::back() 
{
    return first;
}

template <class T>
int& Queue<T>::front() 
{
    return last;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::pop() 
{   
    if (first==NULL)
        return;
    else if (last==NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
    last = last->prev;
    last->next=NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(T element) 
{
    if(first==NULL)
    {
        first=new Node<T>(element);
        last=first;
        first->next=NULL;
        first->prev=NULL;
    } 

    else
    {
        tempNode = first;
        first = new Node<T>(element);
        first->next = tempNode;
        tempNode->prev = first;
    }

}
```

Here is the professor's Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RatinMaze.h"
using namespace std;

void print_header (string h, int fromX,int fromY,int toX,int toY)  {
    cout << h << "from " << "(" << fromY << "," << fromX << ") to ("
         << toY << "," << toX << "):" << endl;
}

int main (){

        RatInMaze* rim = new RatInMaze();
    char maze[13][15]={
        '0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '0','0','0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0',
        '1','1','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0' };

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Queue search ", -1,1,10,10);
    rim->print(rim->searchQueue(-1,1,10,10));

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Stack search ", 0,0,41,1);
    rim->print(rim->searchStack(0,0,41,1));

    int fromX = 0;
    int fromY = 7;
    int toX =  14;
    int toY =  6;

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Rat (stack) searching ",fromX,fromY,toX,toY);
    rim->print(rim->searchStack(fromX,fromY,toX,toY));

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Multiple rats searching ",fromX,fromY,toX,toY);
    rim->print(rim->searchQueue(fromX,fromY,toX,toY));

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Smart rat searching ",fromX,fromY,toX,toY);
    rim->print(rim->searchStackSmart(fromX,fromY,toX,toY));
}
```

I'm new to the language and I'm sure there are lots of things wrong that aren't what I'm asking about; I appreciate any constructive feedback and will make an effort to fix anything you truly see needing it.  Thanks in advance!

Edit: adding Stack.h and Queue.h for clarification

Queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//Create node struct to implement from linked list

template<class T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node(T d, Node* n=NULL): data(d), next(n){}
};


template<class T>
class Queue
{
    private:
        Node<T> *first;
        Node<T> *last;
        Node<T> *tempNode;
        Node<T> *deleteNode;
    public: 
        Queue();
        ~Queue();
        bool empty();
        int size();
        int& front();
        int& back();
        void pop();
        void show();
        void push (T data);



}; //End of class queue

#endif
```

Stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Stack
{
    int stackTop;       //Top of stack
    int stackSize;      //Total stack size
    int emptyStack;     //emptyStack 
    T* ratStack;            //A stack


    public:
                 Stack(int initialCapacity);        //Constructor
                 ~Stack();                          //Destructor
        bool empty() const;                     //Returns true if stack is empty
        int size() const;                       //Returns size of stack
        int top();                          //Returns top of stack
        void pop();                         //Deletes top element
        void push(const int& theElement);   //Puts theElement at the top





}; //End stack class 

#endif
```

Comment: you have not included `Stack.h` in `ratInMaze.cpp`

Comment: @Kunal I included Stack.h in ratInMaze.h.....shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: Yeah that should do. didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

1) They are template classes so the compiler can't see the definitions, when instantiating a new class with particular template argument, because they are in the cpp files. You should define the methods of Stack and Queue in the header files. //There are other ways, too, but this is the simplest solution ;)

2) You should provide methods for loading maze, called load, and printing, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick observation: Shouldn't the pop() member functions of stack and queue return an element? Your searchQueue and searchQueue seem to expect it.